# Issue with Unicode in a Json file

Tags: c#, json, encoding

I have download my data on facebook to work on and do some statistics with it.
unfortunately, some characters doesn't display correctly like 'é' who become 'Ã©'.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sh7P.jpg

When i look on the Json side, i have this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGBw.jpg

my code in C# is pretty simple

```
 private static ListMessages ReadJSON(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            ListMessages messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListMessages>(json);
            return messages;
        }

    }
```

I feel like i'm missing something simple but i can't figure what so i hope someone can help or guide me on this subject.

Comment: Strings in .NET *are* Unicode, specifically UTF16. UTF8 is *not* the same as Unicode, it's just one of the Unicode encodings. If you have such issues it's probably because you used the wrong encoding to load the file.

Comment: BTW [the default](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,137) for StreamReader is to use UTF8 *and* try to detect the encoding from BOMs. Remove `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")` completely. Do you still have issues?

Comment: Finally, `\u009f` etc aren't Unicode characters. They are *escape sequences*. 6 individual characters that are treated as one Unicode character. The same way that `\n` is treated as a newline

Comment: ANother thing, those escape sequences do *not* correspond to french characters. You don't even need escape sequences to type [è](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm). SO runs on .NET, which is why I can simply type the character without escaping. The Unicode escape sequence for  è is `00E8` anyway.

Comment: Where did this file come from? You should probably ask whoever created it to create a *real* UTF8 file. This looks like an attempt to create a 7-bit ANSI file with all non-ANSI characters replaced by escape sequences.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I have deleted the Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8") but i still have the issue.
The file come from Facebook directly via the feature "download your facebook data" where i choose Json instead of HTML.
And yes, for me, 'é' should be '\u00E9' instead of "\u00c3\u00a9" like facebook send me in the file.

Comment: It's a well known issue, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26614323/60761

Comment: Does it exist an equivalent of ftfy for C# or should i use python?

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563179/cant-convert-httpresponsemessage-with-utf8-encoding